# How to sanitize ajax send html data and json data in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have an ajax that sends some html contents and a json structure to a php function. I need the

- json data to be saved to database
- html content to be saved to a php file

  Before that i have to get these values and sanitize them . I have read from wordpress plugin security that $_POST should be sanitized. I read about the `sanitize_*()` series and couldn't find a suitable one for html contents and json structure data. So my question is

  1. If json encoded (json string) data require only be sanitized as plain text or doesn't require sanitization ?
  2. Is `wp_kses` sufficient for html content sanitization in wordpress or there any other functions ?

This is the json structure i am passing via ajax. Purely some text

```
{
    "row": [{
        "data_id": "1001",
        "type": "L",
        "child": [{
            "data_id": "1002",
            "data_type": "M",
            "child": [{
                "data_id": "1003",
                "data_type": "S",
                "child": ""
            }]
        }]
    }],
    "data_id": "Size",
    "data_type": "Cloth"
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For each array key in `$_POST` you should use one of following depending upon the field type:

1. `sanitize_text_field`(All text fields, radio button, select option values, etc.)
2. `sanitize_textarea_field`/`wp_kses`(for text areas)
3. `esc_url`(for url)
4. sanitize_email

This should sanitize most of the element of the Posted data.

PS: If you are in any way directly interacting with database just make sure to use `$wpdb->prepare` and `$wpdb->execute` to secure your database queries(not a necessity but a good practice that I was taught).

Comment: I am using `update_option` to save content to a key. Based on your answer, should i use `wp_kses` for html content ?

Comment: Code sample will be helpful to better understand what you need.

Comment: The key in `$_POST` is not based on any field type. This is `js` processed data send via ajax to php. So what can i do for data in json string form ?

Comment: Also if you have input only from text area then you should go with `sanitize_textarea_field` or `wp_kses`. `wp_kses` is for filtering string based upon allowed html and protocol that you pass. After WordPress 4.7 `sanitize_textarea_field` can be used for sanitization.

Comment: @melvin, you have to individually process each key-value pair from the posted data array.

Comment: It is a json string not an object. So i have to decode it again to check ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194939/discussion-between-faham-shaikh-and-melvin).

Comment: Just one doubt. How can i sanitize key in `$_POST` containing css in  string form (without any tags)

Comment: I didn't get that. Example of css string is `{"color":"red","background-color":"#ffffff","size":"13px","p_t":"10px","m_b":"20px"}`

Comment: [This](https://divpusher.com/blog/wordpress-customizer-sanitization-examples/#css) should be a good example.

Comment: Wow. That was great :)